# How to insert String Values with empty space in PartitionKey column of Azure Table

Tags: string, powershell, azure-table-storage

I am trying to insert values into Azure Table PartitionKey Column. These values is of type String and have spaces between them.
Example

```
$p = "VMWARE-42 3B"
        $r = "VMWARE"
        $entity = @{
            "PartitionKey@odata.type" = "Edm.String";
           "PartitionKey"         = $p;
            "RowKey@odata.type" = "Edm.String";
            "RowKey"                = $r;           
 }
        Set-TableEntity -TableName $tableName -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccessKey $storageAccessKey -Entity $entity  -Verbose
```

I am getting the below error:

> Set-TableEntity - Attempt #0 VERBOSE: PUT
> https://table_url/tableName(PartitionKey='VMWARE-42
> 3B',RowKey='VMWARE') with -1-byte payload Error: Failed to update
> device entry Exception occurred: System.Net.WebException: The remote
> server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.    at
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest
> request)    at
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()

Please any idea on how to solve this?
Please note that when the values are inputed manually, there is no error.
Does Azure Table accept spaces in String values?
Please Note also that: without the space in the string value everything works as expected. the required table is updated.

Comment: You don't show us how you do the actual call... Because of the spaces, do you quote those string values?

Comment: @Theo, thank you. The string is in quote.

Comment: Then please show us the code you use to insert those values. Not in a comment, but as formatted text in your question. Just click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71525105/edit) link underneath. Since the server returns `Forbidden`, are you using the correct credentials to that call?

Comment: yes, I am using the right credential. Without the space in the string value everything works fine. @Theo, I have updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you 'escape' the space character?  for example, replace all spaces with %20 or _x0020_ using p = p.replace(/ /g, '_x0020_').

Comment: Thanks @DonaldKoscheka, tried your suggestion, it did not work still.

Comment: I tested this on my azure table instance.  It accepts spaces in partition keys as well as the escape characters.  Could this by a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your partitionKey and rowKey part in the URL to escaped representation.

```
$Resource = "$TableName(ParitionKey='$PartitionKey',RowKey='$RowKey')"
$Resource = [URI]::EscapeUriString($Resource)
$TableUrl = "https://tableUrl/$($Resource)
```

You must use the same `$Resource` variable in making a hash signature.